# How to remove a character from a string without using native methods nor loops in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, recursion

I need to remove a character at a time from a string, without using native methods or loops. I've found countless ways to do this without native methods OR without loops, but can't seem to find a way to do without either. I was able to come up with a way to use recursion to avoid loops, but not sure how to not use the string.slice() method. I must use recursion. No this is not a homework problem, I'm just practicing for an interview.

The function is supposed to count how many times the target character is repeated (if at all) in an input string.

```js
const countChar = (input, target) => {
    if (input === '') return 0;
    if (input[0] === target) return 1 + countChar(input.slice(1), target);
    return countChar(input.slice(1), target);
}

console.log(countChar('hello world', 'o')); // 2
console.log(countChar('javascript', 'j')); // 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main thing that your current code is using `.slice()` for is to "trim" your string down so that on the next recursive call the first character of your `input` is the next character that you need to check. Instead, you can pass the index of the current character that you want to check, allowing you to avoid the `slice` call:

```js
const countChar = (input, target, i = 0) => {
    if (i >= input.length) return 0;
    if (input[i] === target) return 1 + countChar(input, target, i+1);
    return countChar(input, target, i+1);
}

console.log(countChar('hello world', 'o')); // 2
console.log(countChar('javascript', 'j')); // 1
```

There are of course methods other than `.slice()` that you could use to break up your string, but these still involve "looping"/iterating your string under the hood. One example is to destructure:

```js
const countChar = ([c, ...rest], target) => 
  c ? (c === target) + countChar(rest, target) : 0;

console.log(countChar('hello world', 'o')); // 2
console.log(countChar('javascript', 'j')); // 1
console.log(countChar('', 'j')); // 0
```

The above snippet uses [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) `[c, ...rest]` to extract the first character (stored in `c`) from the first argument passed into your function. The `...rest` takes all characters from the passed in string (excluding the extracted first character) and stores it in the variable `rest`.

The [conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) `? :` is then used to check if the variable `c` has a [truthy value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) (ie: a valid character). `c` will hold a [falsy value](https://%5D%5B4%5D) (`undefined` in our case) when `countChar()` is passed an empty string. If `c` is truthy, then it holds a valid character value, and so the result of `(c === target) + countChar(rest, target)` is used as the return value of the function call.

Here `(c === target)` will either evaluate to `true` or `false`, which when use with  `+ countChar(rest, target)` converts the boolean value to a numeric value, `1` if it is `true`, or `0` if it is `false`. The `: 0;` means that `0` is used as the return value when `c` is a falsy value (ie: no more characters are left to check).

Comment: Thank you so much! The first snippet is incredibly helpful. Could you please elaborate a little on what's going on with the second one though? I'm having a hard time understanding what's going on.

Comment: @R.Bair No worries, I've added a little bit of an explanation under the snippet.